# Spark - only one partition is processed at each node

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I see in my Spark job that usually (but not always) only one partition is being processed on each node. What could be the possible reasons? How can I debug it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the executor's resources configuration:

```
spark.executor.memory
spark.executor.cores
```

These configs control how many executors can run concurrently on each node and therefore -- how many partitions are processed concurrently (by default, every executor processes a single partition).

For example, if your nodes have 8 cores and 32gb memory each and your spark application is defined with:

```
spark.executor.memory=25g
spark.executor.cores=3
```

only one executor will be able to run concurrently on each node and in order to run 2 executors concurrntly the node should have at least 50gb memory.